# to_char function hexadecimal formats error in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hex, to-char

I want to use to_char function in Postgresql but take an error when execute the script.

Oracle version is ok;

```
to_char('7374961057827412212','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') 

result : 66592002042458F4
```

But I could not find Postgresql version and take an error like this;

```
ERROR:  function to_char(text, unknown) does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the table of [formatting codes for numbers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE), you will see that `X` is not supported, and indeed there is no way to get hexadecimal output with `to_char`.

But you can use `to_hex`:

```
SELECT to_hex(7374961057827412212);

      to_hex      
══════════════════
 66592002042458f4
(1 row)
```

The error message you see is because you entered the first argument in single quotes, so it is a string (data type `text`), but there is no `to_char` function to format strings as strings (they are already strings).